# How to send a JSON object as a JWT to a redirection page?

Tags: typescript, angular6, jwt

I am trying to send a JSON object from my application to another webpage. Eg: Sending the UserId to B2C page for processing. The B2C page will not return anything in response until the user performs some action in B2C page and the response is token. The problem is how to safely send the UserId to another page?

I have tried - this.router.navigate method

```
this.router.navigate([url], {
      queryParams: { extension_globalid : action.payload }
    })
```

I expect the parameter to be appended to the url. But it didnt. Also I dont want it to be on url

Comment: JWT is not really a method for passing arbitrary data. You can add *claims* to the token (including for user id), but the other party (that receives the token) must know what to do with it.

Comment: Can you please provide some examples. As I am new to authorization related tasks

Answer (score 0):

Some protocols like OAUth2 and OpenID Connect allows you to use 3 methods for passing the token from one site (authorization endpoint) to another (client callback endpoint):

- The response redirects to the client callback (usually HTTP code 302 or 308) to the callback. The data is set into a **query** parameter added to the callback url

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://client.com/callback?UserId=FOO.bar
```

- The response redirects to the client callback (usually HTTP code 302 or 308) to the callback. The data is set into a **fragment** parameter added to the callback url

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://client.com/callback#UserId=FOO.bar
```

- The response shows a for with a hidden parameter with the data to send. The form can be automatically submitted using JS or the user an be invited to click on a button.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache

<html>
  <head><title>Submit This Form</title></head>
  <body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form method="post" action="https://client.com/callback">
      <input type="hidden" name="UerId"value="FOO.bar"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Please click here!">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share a working example? I am looking for examples to send a JWT token to another URL. Not within a module.